# How to make Publicy Accessible S3 bucket with an IP allowlist via bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating an S3 bucket. The bucket is publicly accessible via the four options in **Block public access (bucket settings)**.

The permissions overview shows public which is good, that is what I want.

When I create a bucket policy to restrict access based off of IP address the bucket switches to **Some Objects are publicly accessible** via the permissions overview.

This is my policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.0.2.0/24"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want all objects publicly accessible via URL such as https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1/puppy.jpg

But putting any policy locks the down the access? How can I create a bucket with objects that can be accessed with anyone with the right IP address only and without them logging into the AWS account.

I tried creating both an allowlist or a blocklist (I tried one policy at a time) but made the bucket no longer public. I want a public bucket locked to an IP address.

Comment: The Block Public Access settings do not make anything public. They simply provide you with options to control whether or not objects can be made public. Your bucket policy should simply allow access if the source IP matches the allowlist IPs. You don't need to deny anything in the bucket policy (it's the default).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. To permit access, you need to add an `Allow` policy, such as:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.0.2.0/24"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This says: "Allow anonymous users to use `GetObject` to retrieve an object from this bucket, if their IP address is in this CIDR".

Please note that the CIDR should be a range of Public IP addresses (not Private addresses).

To add this policy, you will need to deactivate "S3 Block Public Access" for Bucket Policies.

Comment: I did that and the bucket object URL still results in a Access Denied error message. The bucket policy is in effect because I can only access the bucket when I am on the right IP address but when I upload a test object and try to access it via the object URL I get access denied.

Comment: You should test the policy by temporarily removing the `IpAddress` condition. If it works, then the problem lies with that Condition. Please note that `192.0.2.0/24` is quite a strange IP range, because it is similar to the `192.168.x.x` range of private IP addresses, but is actually a public range. Why did you choose this particular CIDR -- is it owned by your organization?

Comment: The Object URL is publicly accessible without the IP condition.

I can only access the bucket config/settings via logging into my AWS account and having that IP address when the condition is set; so it's working slightly?

The policy is pulled from AWS docs. I adjusted the resource arn and IP address to my requirements.

Comment: So your **public** IP address starts with `192.0.2.x`? You can check it by going to https://icanhazip.com/. If so, then the above policy should grant access to you on that IP address. If it is still saying `Access Denied`, can you show us the URL you are trying to use (change the bucket name for privacy), so we can confirm it is in the right format?

Comment: The IP address is correct on the policy. I confirm because I must have that IP when I access the bucket settings on AWS console. Yes when I check my IP address via that site it matches the policy.

I get the object URL when I login into AWS console and check that objects properties. So it is probably right. Format is https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/OBJECTNAME.png (its a png)

Comment: arent access policies obsolete now or being phased out? how do we do this with iam?

Comment: @oldboy An Amazon S3 Bucket Policy works side-by-side with IAM Policies (they use the same syntax). Typically, if you want to give permissions to a specific user or group of users, then it is best to grant the permission via an IAM Policy on the IAM User or IAM Group. If you want to make a bucket public or grant access to cross-account resources, you need to use an S3 Bucket Policy. For the Question above, the only way to grant access to 'anyone' with restrictions on IP address is to use a Bucket Policy, since the users are not authenticating against IAM.